# Upload Vhd to an Azure Page blob in chunks

Tags: azure, file-upload, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to upload a Vhd (sizing atleast 30GB) to a page blob in azure storage in an mvc web application. Due to size of the file i can not upload this large file as a whole as browsers don't allow this large request to be sent. So, the only option is to upload file in chunks (i.e. 4mb). on client size i am able to do chunking and i am sending chunks to my server side controller through an ajax request (in a loop).  But using .net sdk for azure i am not finding a way to upload chunks to a page blob.

P.S There is a way to upload file in chunks in block blob using putblock() and putblocklist() methods and i am able to achieve the uploading in that way but i need to create a VM image out of the uploaded vhd and for that purpose it needs to be a page blob.
So, i would welcome any guidance to show me the way to upload vhd in chunks in a Page Blob using azure .net sdk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`CloudPageBlob.WritePages`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudpageblob.writepages.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) method to upload the chunks of data. Please see this blog post from Azure Storage Team for an example of using this method: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/04/11/using-windows-azure-page-blobs-and-how-to-efficiently-upload-and-download-page-blobs.aspx.

Comment: yes, i have seen this.. but does writepages method append the each coming chunk, coming through ajax request or it simply overwrites?

Comment: It won't automatically append the data. Apart from the byte array that you're sending through your AJAX method, you would also need to send the offset as well. Then whatever data you're sending will be written from the position specified in the offset in the target page blob.

Comment: and using this method one has to send complete file 30GB from Js controller to the one on server side. which causes the issue. as u can see chunking is done (i.e. 4mb) on server side

Comment: Not really ... I am not sure how you're sending chunks but apart from the chunk, you need to send the starting position in the file from where you read the chunk (and that's the offset).

Comment: okay, if a send the offset then i will have to simply assign it to 'vhdOffset' variable to do the trick?

Comment: I'm not sure what `vhdOffset` is .... but this is the value you will pass in `startOffset` member in WritePages method.

Comment: In the link  you provided, 512 bytes is kept as the page size but it makes the upload process really slow for a large upload e.g. a vhd. can we keep 4Mb page size for writing in a page blob?

Comment: Sure you can. Please make sure the page size you choose is a multiple of 512 bytes. Because 4 MB is a multiple of 512 bytes, it is perfectly fine.

Comment: well i tried it but when it wrote the pages with 4mb page size the upload was complete but when it came about creating image from the vhd it showed the error "not a valid page blob" . i uploaded it with 512 bytes page size, upload was complete and image was created successfully. but it (512 bytes page size) almost doubled the upload time. means there is some problem in writing with respect to page size. i am sending 4mb chunks from my js code. can u please tell what should be the appropriate page size for somehow optimized performance w.r.t upload time?

Comment: You need to share your code. Without looking at the code, it would be almost impossible to see why you're getting this error about "not a valid page blob".

Answer (score 1):

You can try [AzCopy tool](http://aka.ms/azcopy) without writing any code.

> AzCopy /Source:C:\myfolder
>   /Dest:https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer
>   /DestKey:mykey /Pattern:abc.vhd /BlobType:Page

Comment: its actually a functionality that should be implemented in my case.

Comment: If you need to implement the functionality programmatically, you can try Microsoft Azure Storage Data Movement Library, which is the core of AzCopy: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement/